# Missing location options when creating new Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to create a new Azure Cosmos DB under my free MPN Subscription and would like to set the location to "(Europe) West Europe" just like I did for my ResourceGroup, but this location (and a lot of other locations) is not available? 
[See the complete list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o3xE.png)

If I create a new Resource Group it's not a problem to choose "(Europe) West Europe" and all the other locations/regions that I can normally choose among.

Anyone who knows why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be due to recent compute shortages in Microsoft Azure due to SARS-COV-2. All the free subscriptions are affected**

https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-cloud-services-demand-up-775-percent-prioritization-rules-in-place-due-to-covid-19/

Answer (score 6):

You can still create resources in West Europe. The locations are unlisted but still available when you create your resources using ARM templates.

To achieve this, follow these simple steps:

1. configure your resource up to the point where you need to create it, but use one of the listed locations. Do not create the resource.
2. In the "Review + Create" page of the wizard, choose "Download a template for automation".
3. Choose Deploy
4. Change 'Location' to `westeurope` and 'Location Name' to `West Europe`, agree terms and conditions and click 'Purchase'

Comment: I've encountered the same issue, and although I was able to force the DB creation by using mstaessen's method described above, it was not functional. The issue seems to be with the fact that I'm using a **Pay-As-You-Go subscription** - switching from a Pay-As-You-Go to a CSP subscription made all the regions available.

Comment: Tried the same when deploying cosmos and failed: {
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The requested region 'South Afica North' is not supported.\r\nActivityId: 56f178da-3e55-4731-8f44-d63328cf026a, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"
    }
}