# Cant create a server in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to make an SQL Instance in Microsoft Azure but every server location is unavailable.

[image]

My subscription is just a trial but i think creating server under a trial subscription is available. I have tried all the location but always receiving the same result.

Comment: Could be because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031962/missing-location-options-when-creating-new-azure-cosmos-db. Microsoft is putting in some constraints on new resources creation.

Comment: Damn. Thats how covid affect even cloud services

Comment: hI @GeraldTDPI,  If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, many peoples have the same problem.

You could reference the [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted) which The MSFT gave for us:

To all our Azure SQL Database customers,

Please read the following communication pertaining to this ongoing issue: [Our commitment to customers and Microsoft cloud services continuity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/).

For more updated information, Please visit our [Banner Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3865be66-8d81-443d-902b-8e5a8a34fbe7/ongoing-issue-unable-to-provision-azure-sql-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted) which we will be updating regularly as we get more information or resolution for the same.

If you are in a situation where you are in an immediate need to deploy services and are being blocked in doing so, please use the [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest) to raise your request.

Microsoft Azure is committed to helping our customers. We’ll continue to monitor the situation and will keep you updated. We appreciate your patience and apologize for any inconvenience caused.

Regards,
Azure CXP Community Engineering

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just talked with their representative and they said that free services cant be prioritize right now due to high demand of cloud services because of COVID so they suggest to upgrade my subscription to paid one then i can now be able to create Sql Servers